# Is there an app for iPhone to record the audio output streaming of any other app ?

Tags: iphone, ios

Is there an app for iPhone/iPad to record the audio output streaming of any other app ?

I need to record the audio streamed from other apps and not the audio from the microphone.

thanks

Comment: This probably is technically impossible without a jailbreak. Is jailbreaking an option?

Comment: No it isn't. It is a pity, because I've downloaded an app streaming radio music and I would like to save some tracks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the App on the Phone, there may be an export option for streamed files. An alternative might be to extract the desired file(s) from the iPhone backup on your computer.

Once you have the (large) stream file on your Mac (?), you can extract the desired tracks from the file. For lossless MP3 editing you might want to try Rogue Amoeba’s [Fission](http://rogueamoeba.com/fission/) or Macsome [Audio Editor](http://www.macsome.com/audio-editor-mac/index.html) (free).

Comment: I don't have a stream file. The app is a radio which is streaming content from the internet.

Comment: I could recommend [Internet Radio Box](http://itunes.apple.com/en/app/internet-radio-box/id293623806?mt=8), a streaming audio app for iPhone (no affiliation). It allows for export of the recorded file via a built-in Web server.

Answer (score 5):

This link shows the steps on mac. https://www.apptamin.com/blog/capture-iphone-ipad-screen-video/

You use Quicktime, 
Connect your iPhone or iPad to your Mac via the lightning cable.
Open QuickTime player.
Click File then select 'New Audio Recording'
A recording window will appear.
Select the Mic of your iPhone if you want to record music/sound effects.
Click the Record button.
You will not hear the sound, but the levels show the input.

Answer (score -3):

Try audials Tunebite premium. This should record from any audio stream